# ASP.NET File Uploader Control without Flash

Tags: asp.net, ajax, flash, file-upload

I am using obout file upload control ( http://www.obout.com/Obout.Ajax.UI/FileUpload/ ) for years and it is working fine. I am pretty comfortable with it. But now my customer come with a new requirement. He want to have a file upload control without flash. But he requires the features:

1. Validating File Size
2. Progress Bar

Do anybody have solution for this? Can anybody guide me with a step-by-step procedure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in ie9 and older browsers, as well as Android 2.3.x and older.  For other browsers, that is, ones that support the file api: progress bars and file size validation are some of the many features that Fine Uploader provides. There are no required dependencies either.   Have a look at the [demo page](http://fineuploader.com) for more info.